# Tube puncture at same place

Tags: innertube, puncture

1st picture - small rip on inner side of the tube.

Rim looks good, rip tape also good.

I fixed it 2 times using slime patch kit, first time it failed when I was inflating tube after patching it, 2nd time I rode it less than half mile and patch ripped again from same place.

Any idea why it keeps failing? Am I not using the patch correctly?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - that's a well illustrated question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have two problems here:

1. Whatever caused the flat in the first place has not been fixed. Since it's on the rim side of the tube, that's where the problem must be. Perhaps a protruding spoke. It might seem OK when you run your finger over it, but when you put 100 psi in the tube, it's pressed into the spoke openings.
2. For the first patch job, you clearly didn't get good adhesion. There are a few possible explanations:

   1. You didn't do a good job cleaning the patching site on the tube--this is what the sandpaper is for. The innertube is covered with mold-release compound from its manufacture, and this interferes with the vulcanizing agent doing its thing. You can also wash the area with soap and water.
   2. You didn't use enough vulcanizing agent. That little tube dries out pretty quickly--there's no reason to be sparing with it.
   3. You didn't give the vulcanizing agent enough time to set up.

Comment: point 2 still gets me - I either miss a couple mm of the edge and that's enough to start it peeling up, or I put acres too much on.